# Jest: can spy on some Class private functions but not others

Tags: typescript, class, jestjs, private

I'm trying to test a class with private methods, for example:

```js
class MyClass {
  private toggleState(): void {
    this.myState = true;
  }

  private updateFile(filePath: string): void {
    someFunctionThatUpdatesFile()
  }

  private openFile(filePath: string): void {
    someFunctionThatOpensFile()
  }

  private getPath(file: string): string {
    return "/some/path/to/file"
  }

}
```

And in my tests:

```js
test("my test", () => {
  const spyGetPath = jest.spyOn(MyClass.prototype as any, "getPath") // Works as expected
  const spyOpenFile = jest.spyOn(MyClass.prototype as any, "openFile") // Work as expected

  const spyToggleState = jest.spyOn(MyClass.prototype as any, "toggleState") // Cannot spy the toggleState property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
  const spyUpdateFile = jest.spyOn(MyClass.prototype as any, "updateFile") // Cannot spy the updateFile property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
});
```

Why would the first 2 spy's work fine, but the other 2 don't?
What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I face same problem, have you resolved it?

Comment: Unfortunately not